# How to save a nested relationship in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I am trying to save a nested relationship in Django REST Framework following the [Django REST Framework guide](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) but I couldn't do that.

I have a class "Asiento" which is a foregin key for another class "Apunte". When I get every "Asiento" Django REST Framework returns them and all of their "Apunte" objects. This works, but when I try to create/update an "Asiento" with writable nested serializers I get that `AsientoSerializer(data=data).is_valid() == False`.

**My models:**

```py
class Apunte(TxerpadBase):
    debe = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, max_digits=18, decimal_places=6)
    haber = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, max_digits=18, decimal_places=6)
    cuenta = models.ForeignKey(Cuenta, related_name='mayor', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    partner = models.ForeignKey(Partner, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    asiento = models.ForeignKey(Asiento, related_name='apuntes')
    fecha = models.DateField()
    recc = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    conciliacion = models.ForeignKey('Conciliacion', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    estado = FSMField(default='borrador')


class Asiento(TxerpadBase):
    numero = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    fecha = models.DateField(blank=True, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    libro = models.ForeignKey('Libro', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    periodo = models.ForeignKey(Periodo, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    estado = FSMField(default='borrador')
```

**My serializers:**

```py
class ApunteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fecha = serializers.DateField(
        format='%d-%m-%Y', input_formats=('%d-%m-%Y',),
        error_messages={'invalid': 'La fecha del apunte no esta en el formato correcto.'}
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Apunte


class AsientoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fecha = serializers.DateField(
        format='%d-%m-%Y', input_formats=('%d-%m-%Y',),
        error_messages={'invalid': 'La fecha del asiento no esta en el formato correcto.'}
    )
    apuntes = ApunteSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Asiento

    def create(self, data):
        apuntes_data = data['apuntes']
        asiento_data = data
        asiento_data['fecha'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(asiento_data['fecha'], '%d-%m-%Y').date()
        del asiento_data['apuntes']
        asiento = Asiento.objects.create(**asiento_data)
        for apunte in apuntes_data:
            apunte['fecha'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(apunte['fecha'], '%d-%m-%Y').date()
            Apunte.objects.create(asiento=asiento, **apunte)
```

**My viewset:**

```py
class AsientoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Asiento.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AsientoSerializer

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # JSON dictionary is inside validated_data.data
        serializer = AsientoSerializer(data=validated_data.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            raise AttributeError('Error al validar')
```

This is JSON that I send with my request:

```json
{
    u'name': u'prueba 3000', 
    u'periodo': 13, 
    u'fecha': u'18-02-2016', 
    u'numero': None, 
    u'estado': u'borrador', 
    u'libro': 1, 
    u'apuntes': [
        {
            u'name': u'a', 
            u'recc': False, 
            u'debe': u'1', 
            u'haber': u'0.00', 
            u'cuenta': u'5', 
            u'partner': 8, u'fecha': 
            u'18-02-2016', 
            u'conciliacion': u''
        }
    ]
}
```

If I debug the code only "create" method which executes is viewset's method, but it doesn't run "create" method from serializer.

With this code I can't save an "Asiento" neither an "Apunte". What am I doing wrong? Thank you for any answere!

I am using python 2.7 (I can't update it for external reasons) and Django REST Framework 3.3.2.

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found that my problem was that "asiento" attribute in "Apunte" object can't be null and I wasn't sending it. Now, I have changed "asiento" attribute in "Apunte" object and serializer finally works, and it is no needed "create" method on ViewSet.

Thanks to everyone for your answeres.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you should do in case of invalid serialization is to look at the returned message (serializer.data). It'll help you understand what's going wrong.

My blind guess here is that you're missing the `queryset` argument relating to the nested serializer. If not set, DRF will consider those fields as read only.

Edit: After the OP edition, the issue comes from the viewset.
You need to call `serializer.save()` if the serializer is valid.
Have a look at how the [CreateMixin](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L18) does it.

Comment: My seriealizer.data returns a dictionary with data information.  

I'm not sure what do you mean with I am missing the `queryset`. What do you suggest me to put? Thanks!

Comment: What I meant is explained [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#the-queryset-argument). Could you provide the serializer.data so we can see where you validation fails ?

Comment: This is what I get doing `serializer.data`:

{'apuntes': [{u'name': u'a', u'recc': False, u'debe': u'1', u'haber': u'0.00', u'cuenta': u'5', u'partner': 8, u'fecha': u'18-02-2016', u'conciliacion': u''}], 'periodo': 13, 'fecha': u'18-02-2016', 'numero': None, 'estado': u'borrador', 'libro': 1, 'name': u'prueba 3000'}

Comment: Alright, your custom viewset is in cause, I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: But `serializer.is_valid()` is still false, so it never does `serializer.save()`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if thats the solution. But the `create` method of a serializer has to return the created object.
Try adding `return` to your last line

Comment: It is still invalid. But thank you, you are right that I forgot to put return statement.

Comment: As you are only sending one Asiento you should remove the loop over apuntes_data.

Comment: Django REST Framwork documentation specify that I must create the "Asiento" in first place and then I have to loop "Apunte" objects passing as "asiento" field for "Apunte" that one I have just create. So I need to loop "Apunte" object, don't I?

Comment: I thuink you misunderstood that. You should loop over apuntes creation, mot over asiento

Comment: I loop over "Apunte" objects in "Asiento" creation. I don't understand you. Could you be more specific please?